# How do I filter if data is null it will not be show up?

Tags: javascript

I'm currently working with JavaScript and API to display data. There is some user did not have a file while some may have file. Below is what I'm working on. But it does not work, some user have attached their file but with my code it not showing. How do I fix this ?

```
 a.sale.note.map((a) => {

                       let file ='';

                            a.supervise.map((a) => {
                                file += a.file_name;
                            });

                            
                            readInfo += `
                                <div class="ticket-msg-item is-mine">
                                    <div class="ticket-msg-from">
                                        <div class="ticket-msg-user user-card">
                                            <div class="user-avatar bg-info">
                                                <span>Sale Customer</span>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="user-info">
                                                <span class="lead-text">${a.nickname}</span>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="ticket-msg-comment">
                                        <p>${a.description}</p>
                                    </div>`

                                    if (file== null){
                                    
                                    `
                                                <p> No file </p>            
                                        
                                    `;    
                                    } 
                                    else{
                                             `
                                           
                                            
                                                <a href="${file}">
                                                    <em class="icon ni ni-download"> File</em>
                                                </a>                
                                        
                                          
                                     `;   

                                    }               
                        });
```

How do I get output that will display only user with file will be able to have `File` displayed and user with no file will have `No File` displayed ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your initial value for variable `file` is an empty string, compare it to an empty string instead of `null`:

```
if (file === "")
```

Also, you forgot add the result of the condition to `readInfo` variable

Comment: still same, it did not read my if else statement

Comment: yes it did, the problem is that your if/else does absolutely nothing, because it's result not applied to anything. You need assign it to something like `if (blah) readInfo += "blah"; else readInfo += "not blah";`

Comment: What you mean by 'not reading your if else statement'? That is not possible. Either if or else is definitely read! You can have a console.log('if') in your if statement and a  console.log('else') in your else statement to get a better tracking. @vanowm

Comment: how do I put the condition in to the `readInfo` ?

Comment: @teefal, I think you are confused about `;` character in Javascript. It represent end of statement, however it can be omitted if a new line used. So when you terminated string with " ` " you terminated the string statement. Whatever comes after that will not affect that string unless you explicitly tell it to. So  what you need is add additional string to your `readInfo` variable in that condition: `if (file === "") { readInfo += "<p> No file </p>" } else { readInfo += "blah" }`

Comment: fully understood now, thank you for explaining :)